# I am trying to fetch All text(tweet like a post) from database. REACT NATIVE

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch All text(tweet like a post) from database.but its showing error TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...posts.map...')

**below is my code:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
    import {ActivityIndicator, Text, View, FlatList} from 'react-native';
    import stylesheet from '../src/styles/HomeStyle';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

    function FeedScreen() {
      // const [posts, setPosts] = useState('loading');
      const [posts, setPosts] = useState({
        text: '',
        id: '',
      });
      const Boiler = async () => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        fetch('http://192.168.1.5:3000/post', {
          headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
          }),
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            setPosts(res.posts);
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        Boiler();
      }, []);

      return (
        <View style={stylesheet.container}>
          {posts.map(post => (
            <Text key={post.id}>{post.text}</Text>
          ))}
        </View>
      );
    }

    export default FeedScreen;
```

Comment: `posts` initial value is an object so it can't be mapped. Maybe it should be: `[{text: "",id: ""}]` or simply `[]`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the initial value for posts is a post and not an array of posts. I also renamed `Boiler` as initial uppercase should be reserved for components or classes, and moved it inside the `useEffect`:

```
const FeedScreen = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]); // Here was the issue

    useEffect(() => {
        const boiler = async () => {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
            fetch("http://192.168.1.5:3000/post", {
                headers: new Headers({
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
                })
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    setPosts(res.posts);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        };

        boiler();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={stylesheet.container}>
            {posts.map(post => (
                <Text key={post.id}>{post.text}</Text>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
};

export default FeedScreen;
```